# Set selected option by text and reset to default option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html select element with a default option `Select an option` and I'm trying to change it when I click in some other element, for example: I have a button with value = `MyText select option`, if I click in this element I want to search if that text exists on my select options, I do this with **contains** jQuery method and seems to work, the problem is that I can have more than one elements with text and I don't know what is wrong with my code but seems to work only the first time. Here is an example of my problem:

> Two buttons, I click on the first button and works fine, then I click on the second and works too, but then I click on the first again doesnt work!

Also I want to create a reset option, for this I'm using `.prop('selectedIndex',  0)` but doesnt work.

Here is my example code:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#Sel option:contains(' + value + ')').attr("selected", true);

});

$('.btn2').click(function() {
  $('#Sel').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button value="Button 1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button value="Button 2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn2">Reset</button>

<select name="" id="Sel">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Button 1</option>
  <option value="2">Button 2</option>
</select>
```

PD: If there is an option to reset all my inputs (select, text, number, etc.) by clicking on input type="reset" that could be a solution for my reset problem, because I also tried by clicking on reset input with (window.MyForm.reset()) but my last selected option is not reseted.

Comment: What, exactly, should clicking on the second button (button2) accomplish?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Clicking any button should change the selected option, but I you test my code this only works the first time you click every button.

Comment: I would recommend updating your question to reflect the facts you've commented on charlieftl's answer.

Comment: @chazsolo There is it! `if I click in this element I want to search if that text exists on my select options, I do this with contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `selected` **attribute** to the options, set the `selected` **property**. This forces the browser to unselect all other selected options (if list is not `<select multiple>`).

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#Sel option:contains(' + value + ')').prop("selected", true);
});
```

Alternatively, you can read the `index` property and set `selectedIndex` on the list, which is IMO more clear behaviour.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var index = $('#Sel option:contains(' + value + ')').prop("index");
  $('#Sel').prop('selectedIndex', index);
});
```

Also, the `disabled` first option may cause trouble in some browsers when resetting the form.

Comment: This help me to set selected option by text! Now I'm trying to solve the issue reseting the form, in chrome there is no problem for the moment, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you check the text and use the same function to change the value of `select` tag, you can do what you want perfectly.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('#Sel option').each(function(index){
    if($(this).text() == val)
      $('#Sel').prop('selectedIndex', index);
  });
});

$('.btn2').click(function() {
  $('#Sel').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button value="Button 1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button value="Button 2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn2">Reset</button>

<select name="" id="Sel">
  <option value="0" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Button 1</option>
  <option value="2">Button 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This could be another form to solve my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to use actual values need in buttons and then simply use `val()` on the select

```
<button value="1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button value="2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button value="0" class="btn">Reset</button>
```

Then one listener would work for all 3

```
$('.btn').click(function() {      
  $('#Sel').val($(this).val());    
});
```

As for clearing all other inputs just set value to empty string

```
$(':input').not('select').val('')
```

Comment: Yes, I know that is simple using .val(), the problem is that I need to selec the option by text property, using buttons was an example but I could do this with inputs, labels, etc. I need to use .text

Comment: just remove `disabled` from`<option>`

Comment: That works using .val( ) but like I said I cant select the .val() of my option, I need to select an option by text option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused with option values... and setting the value of the selector doesn't leave any stray cleanup you have to do manually setting attrs.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var buttonValue = $(this).val();
  var optionValue = $("#Sel option:contains("+buttonValue+")").val();
  $("#Sel").val(optionValue);
});

$('.btn2').click(function() {
  $('#Sel').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```